# Read mixed variables from xlsx file in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsx

I want to read xlsx file in matlab. xlsx file contains numeric and non numeric (string) variables. When I try to read file by `xlsread(filename)`, non-numeric variables are seen like `NaN`. I mean;
my xlsx files like;

```
13      96      partly cloudy
12      98      clear
13      99      clear
14      97      partly cloudy
```

but when I read by  `xlsread(filename)`, the values appear like below;

```
13      96      Nan
12      98      Nan
13      99      Nan
14      97      Nan
```

How to I read all type of values and assign a variable from xlsx file in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one output, `xlsread` only returns the numeric data.  Instead, you should do this:

```
[~, ~, data] = xlsread(filename);
```

It will return a cell array containing all the contents of the file (the first two outputs, ignored here using `~`, are just the numeric contents, and just the text contents)